# Rounding to n significant digits

Tags: matlab, floating-point, digits, significant-digits

I'm trying to write code in MATLAB that will round number to certain (as I ask) significant digits.

I'm not sure how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html

Comment: You can also use [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26212-round-with-significant-digits/content/roundsd.m).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To round to `d` **significant digits**:

```
>> d = 3; %// number of digits
>> x = 5.237234; %// example number

>> D = 10^(d-ceil(log10(x)));
>> y = round(x*D)/D
y =
    5.2400
```

To round to `d` **decimal digits**:

```
>> d = 3; %// number of digits
>> x = 5.237234; %// example number

>> D = 10^d;
>> y = round(x*D)/D
y =
    5.2370
```

**EDIT**

Actually it's easier: the [`round`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) function supports these options:

```
>> d = 3;
>> x = 5.237234;
>> y = round(x, d, 'significant')
y =
    5.2400

>> d = 3;
>> x = 5.237234;
>> y = round(x, d) %// or y = round(x, d, 'decimals')
y =
    5.2370
```

Comment: why b(2)=b(3)


      b=[sdround(pi/4,3),sdround(pi/4,4),sdround(pi/4,9)]

b =

    0.7850    0.7854    0.7854

Comment: @saharz That's just a displaying issue. Try `format long`

Comment: Note that octave doesn't have the upgraded `round` function, so the earlier part of this answer is still useful for open source users.