# How to round off number in MATLAB to desired decimal points?

Tags: matlab

I want to round of 23.456 as 23.5 how to do this.

I could not find any specific function for this in MATLAB.

Comment: Pretty dumb but official response Related http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94046-how-can-i-round-a-number-to-any-precision-i-define

Comment: any release >= 2014b has this [functionality](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) built-in: `Y = round(X,N)` rounds to `N` digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rounding to n significant digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917900/rounding-to-n-significant-digits)

Comment: @serial `Y = round(X,N)` doesn't work in MATLAB 2013a

Comment: @dSb I'm aware of that: "_any release >= 2014b_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
Loki=[13.47471556 12.36547 21.0; 45.31 54.326 456.23; 12.2 45.14 65.39]
Ndecimals = 1 ;  
Thor = 10.^Ndecimals ;
Loki = round(Thor*Loki)/Thor
```

See the round off Loki

```
Loki (default)
   13.4747   12.3655   21.0000
   45.3100   54.3260  456.2300
   12.2000   45.1400   65.3900


Loki (round off)
   13.5000   12.4000   21.0000
   45.3000   54.3000  456.2000
   12.2000   45.1000   65.4000
```